# Conditionals: What is wrong with my if/else statements?

Tags: conditional-tags

```
<?php if( $settings['logo']) : ?>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><img src="<?php echo $settings['logo']; ?>"/></a>

<?php else if ( $settings['logo_option'] == 'image' && !$settings['logo'] ) : ?>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/logo.png"/></a>

<?php else if( $settings['logo_option'] == 'text' && !$settings['logo'] ) : ?>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>

<?php else : ?>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What is happening that shouldn't be? Or visa-versa?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF, expecting ':'

Comment: error on the first else if statement I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the spaces in your `else if`s such that they become `elseif`s. PHP interprets `else if` as though it were an `if` conditional nested within an `else`, and as such is expecting the `else :` to match your `if :` when it encounters `else{ if(){} }` instead. See [4661508](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661508/underlying-difference-between-elseif-vs-else-if) and [3385213](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385213/whats-the-difference-between-if-and-elseif) for more precise details :)

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you. I didn't know that about these kinds of statements.